# How to select which account is logged in at system startup, or none?

Tags: login, startup, users, accounts

I'm helping out some friends with a tiny hospitality business where one desktop computer has some files used by the business in one account "hotel" but it's mostly used by guests for browsing the web in another account "guest".

It's low security, we're not worried about hacking or anything. But we don't want people accidentally moving our files or anything either.

But the system always boots into the "hotel" account without asking for a password, even though the account has a password.

We want it to boot into the "guest" account.

I know a bit about computers generally and Linux but not much about Ubuntu and the ever-changing graphical environment the Linuxes are going through these days. We've looked through the obvious settings/preferences/options and I've done some Googling. I know this should be obvious easy stuff but I can't find it.

(We're running 10.04 LTS on a generic aging Intel box.)

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Looks like when the installation of the Ubuntu on the machine, someone ticked "log in automatically". Since I'm using the Kubuntu, I might not help a lot but try looking more into the "User Account" or "Your Profile" or anything similar to it. Perhaps, you can change the setting there. I'm thinking about option "require password to log in" or something similar when you found the right setting....

When I'm on Kubuntu, I found this :

[image: Automated User Log-In Selection]

I really hope that you can find something similar to this, or change your machine to Kubuntu, it is pretty nice and just like windows. Hope that I'm helping you my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Can you go System => Administration => Login Screen, Unlock the window, then change the user for automatic login there?

Or is the option not there?

The program that is launched is 'gdmsetup' which should be there if you have GDM installed. (the default login manager - if you don't know what I am talking about, and you use ubuntu with gnome, then you probably are using GDM).

Comment: I'll check this tomorrow and let you know what happens.